# Android Studio, downloading image form url/app has stopped working

Tags: save, save-image

Hi could you help me find out why my app stops working when I want to download image from url, here is the code

```
    public void getOnClick(View view) throws IOException {

    urlAdress = new URL("http://www.cosmeticsurgerytruth.com/blog/wp-     content/uploads/2010/11/Capri.jpg");
    InputStream is = urlAdress.openStream();
    filename = Uri.parse(urlAdress.toString()).getLastPathSegment();
    outputFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),filename);
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    byte[] b = new byte[2048];
    int length;

    while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
        os.write(b, 0, length);

        is.close();
        os.close();
```

I was also trying to use some code from similar topics but I get same message

> Your app has stopped working

and it shuts down

Comment: @vspallas do you have any idea?
It seems to be  easy thing

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

The problem is that you are trying to download the image from the UIThread. You have to create a class which extends to AsyncTask class and make the download on the doInBackground method

```
private class DownloadAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private Context context;

        DownloadAsync(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                URL urlAdress = urlAdress = new URL("http://www.cosmeticsurgerytruth.com/blog/wp-     content/uploads/2010/11/Capri.jpg");
                InputStream is = urlAdress.openStream();
                String filename = Uri.parse(urlAdress.toString()).getLastPathSegment();
                File outputFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(), filename);
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                byte[] b = new byte[2048];
                int length;

                while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                    os.write(b, 0, length);

                    is.close();
                    os.close();

                    return null;
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
```

Then you can execute like this

```
public void getOnClick(View view){
   new DownloadAsync(this).execute();
}
```

Comment: thank you man but...
after clicking the Button nothing is happening

epic frustration

Comment: i Click button and i assume image from url will be saved on my device right? so after i press my button, nothing is happening, i was trying to search file everywhere on my phone but it is not there:(

Comment: did you set  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 on the manifest?

Comment: Yes and Internet permission too

Comment: if you don't tell what exception it throws I can't help you

Comment: there is no exception, app just does nothing after click, bu thx anyway